# WCF getting the phisical path of URL adress

Tags: wcf, mappath

I'm new at WCF and i'm trying to create a service, it needs to convert url to server path. For example:
Gets -> "www.sample.com/client1"
Returns -> "c://samplefolder/sampleproject/client1"

I'm trying this code:

```
string realPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(URL);
```

but I get `The relative virtual path 'http://localhost:5353' is not allowed here`

Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the relative path. Instead of the url "http://www.sample.com/client1" use "~/client1" (the symbol '~' specifies the root folder of your application)

Comment: Thanks, just found the issue. I was about to post it :P